# Как реализовать при следующем наведении новый цвет?

Tags: javascript, html

Как реализовать при следующем наведении новый цвет?

При первом наведении зелёный, при втором красный, при третьем желтый и так по кругу.

```js
let getId = id => document.getElementById(id);


getId('block').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    
})
getId('block').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = '';
})
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#block{
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: violet;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="block"></div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Массив с цветами + счетчик индекса добавил. В остальном код остался прежним почти.

```js
let getId = id => document.getElementById(id);
let colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow'];
let counter = 0;

getId('block').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = colors[counter];
    if(counter >= 2) {
      counter = 0;
    } else {
      counter++;
    }    
})
getId('block').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = '';
})
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#block{
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: violet;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="block"></div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Упс. Не успел )))

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let color = 1;
  let getId = id => document.getElementById(id);


  getId('block').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  switch (color) {
    case 1: this.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; break;
    case 2: this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; break;
    case 3: this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; break;
    default: break
  }
  if (color == 3)
    color = 1;
  else
    color++;
  })

})
```

Остальное ваше